Setting up cron in CiviCRM running in Wordpress (Pantheon hosting)
I am having a lot of issues in trying to setting up cron in Wordpress (Pantheon hosting).
I am trying to make it work by using EasyCron, I am following this guide but I am constantly getting 500 errors, all related to undefined constants/functions in Civicrm.settings.php
I am slowing fixing every error one by one but it's painful and now I am questioning but maybe my civicrm.settings.php is not set up correctly to be fully compatible with Wordpress/Pantheon.
I have found a 4 years old civicrm.settings.phprelated to Wordpress/Pantheon but I am wondering can help me out and share a more recent one.
Thanks!

I am having similar problem with EasyCron - using a Apache server (php 8.3.0, MySQL 8.0.16) on my PC ("Local by Flywheel"). The error I get is " dial tcp: lookup 241017-sandpit.local: no such host". Apparently I need to bind my Local site to a static IP address. I have no idea how to do this.

If you have cPanel just add the script in there using the cron setting.

I found no solution for localhost - so will wait till the site is hosted (with C panel)., to try again.

Pantheon’s unique setup can make configuring cron for CiviCRM tricky. Double-check your civicrm.settings.php file to ensure paths and constants like CIVICRM_UF are correctly set for WordPress and Pantheon. For EasyCron, verify you're using the proper URL, such as:
https://your-site.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron&key=YOUR_CIVICRM_KEY.
If the 500 errors persist, it could be related to file paths or your PHP version. You might also try using a WordPress plugin like WP Crontrol to simplify managing cron jobs.
By the way, are you using Pantheon exclusively? I’ve been trying out Cloudways recently as I got a 40% Black Friday discount and found managing cron jobs directly from their platform really convenient. It might be worth exploring if you’re open to alternatives.
